# Convert a simple array to a two dimensional array of objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to convert this:

```
[null, 1890, null, NGU]
```

...into this:

```
[[], [1890], [], [NGU]]
```

I've tried creating a new array and pushing values to it, but that just ends up looking the same. Honestly, I'm unsure of what to even call what I'm trying to create. Is it a two-dimensional array or an array of objects?

This is for a google app script and [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) calls it a two-dimensional array of values.

Comment: This is really a JavaScript question, more than (or as well as) a GAS question, since you would be writing JavaScript in your GAS script to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var arr = [null, 1890, null, 'NGU']
var arr2d = arr.map(x => [x])

console.log(arr2d) // output --> [ [ null ], [ 1890 ], [ null ], [ 'NGU' ] ]
```